# Assign event in javasscript in Dynamics CRM 365(UCI)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

How to get Assign event when User does Assign to "Me" through assign button.I am using UCI interface but while user assigning to himself by assign button, save event does not trigger.

```
executionContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode() == 47
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a record is reassigned, the `ownerid` attribute value changes. You can therefore register an `onChange` event against this attribute either programmatically:

```
formContext.getAttribute("ownerid").addOnChange(() => alert("My code has triggered"));
```

Or using the form editor and attaching your function to the `onChange` event of `ownerid`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Dave Clark's answer, don't forget to to pass the function you're binding the on change event to.

```
formContext.getAttribute(arg).addOnChange(myFunction)
```

Sidenote, binding onChange events automatically passes the execution context to the function you're binding to, just make sure to receive it as a parameter.